# Attaching arbitrary Id to Google Contact Address

Tags: c#, google-api, gdata, google-data

I am trying to do a synchronization between Google Contacts (via their their Data API) and our internal system.
I want to be able to attach our Address ID to the Google Structured Address but I can't seem to find a way.

I tried to add it as custom property, Extension Element and everything I could think of but to no avail.

My best shot was to add ExtensionFactory, it seems to go to Google (I was sniffing around and saw it going to their system) but never came back. Probably they don't accept Extension Factories / Extension Element to the addresses but only to the contacts?

So - is it possible to attach an ID to address (I know I can attach to contact but I want to be able to attach to address as one contact may have many addresses).

I am using C# and downloaded the Google Data Contacts API C# library.

Please ask for more information should you need it.

Comment: sorry - misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do it. The API doesn't allow attaching arbitrary data to the `gd:structuredPostalAddress` field.

Your best bet is to attach the data to the contact (as `gd:extendedProperty`) and link it to a particular address using some unique identifier. This unique identifier could be hash of the address data. Or, if you don't care about occasional misses, it could be a combination of `gd:rel` value and the position of the address in the list.

Comment: Hashing the address is error prone. If the user edit it in the Google interface - we're in trouble. Hashing rel + position won't work as well, if we have 3 addresses and the user deletes the second, the third will become second in the list. Am I missing something here? Anyway, if you are absolutelly positive that there is no way to attach arbitrary data to address, this can count as answer as well, I'll just wait for some more opinions and mark it if it happens to be the case ...

Comment: You didn't explicitly ask for the ID to be kept when the address is changed in the web interface and/or other application. That's why I suggested the hashing. Combination of gd:rel and position is not error prone, but it's probably the best you can get. It's certainly better than position alone.

Comment: Btw, I am reasonably sure that there is no way to round-trip arbitrary data along with the address. I can't provide any additional sources to support this claim, but I've written the Google Contacts synchronization for eM Client (an Outlook-like application). Also, other interfaces to Google Contacts Data (ActiveSync and Portable Contacts) wouldn't be able to round-trip the information anyway.

Comment: Ok, Filip, thanks for your help!
Your approach seems to be the best thign we can do. I will add some more things in our internal system and we will probably cover most of the cases.